# React JS Typescript usestate with boolean

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have along time with this and I don't understand the error, so look it this I have this line:

```
function App() {

  const [ isLogged, setIsLogged ] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const changedLogging = () => {
    setIsLogged( !isLogged );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        {
          !isLogged? <Login changedLogging={ changedLogging } />
          : 
            <div>
              <Header changedLogging={ changedLogging } />
              <Profile />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
  );
}


login.tsx

const OnSubmit = ( event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>  ) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
   props.changedLogging;
}

header.tsx
          <Button
            {...{
              key: 'out',
              color: "inherit",
              to: props.changedLogging,
              component: RouterLink,
              className: menuButton,
            }}
          > 
            Out
          </Button>
```

and when it running this error is showing:
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions

Do you know why???

I'm trying to create a simple login using file .tsx, the variable isLogged is to controlate a simple login. so when a user is logging the variable isLogged change to true and qhen the user is out the variable is false

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it like this:

```
const [ isLogged, setIsLogged ] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
```

The mistake is in calling the function.

You need to call it like this.

`props.changedLogging();`

Comment: the error is showing yet,,, the error is in setIsLogged( !isLogged );

Comment: Could you please show from where and how you are calling `changedLogging` function?

Comment: Here you are passing the function as props. Please add the code from where you are calling the function.

Comment: ready it!... so do you think the error is props.changedLogging ????

Comment: Right...the error is in `props.changedLogging` . You need to call this function like `props.changedLogging()`.

Comment: Happy to help :) . Please mark the upvote answer if you think it answers your question. Thanks.